# save button not saving because of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am having some trouble with my save button. When applying the specified JavaScript for my button it doesn't save the information. But if I remove the JavaScript the button works and saves the information fine.

```
(function ($) {

Views.Accounts = {
    AddSaveBtnEvents: function () {
        $(".savebtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $("#Username,#ProfileName").keyup(function(event) {
            $(event.target).siblings('.savebtn').removeAttr('disabled', true);
        });

            $(".savebtn").click(function () {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    } 
 };

$.views.Accounts.AddSaveBtnEvents();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I see that your script is intended to disable and re-enable the button. Is the problem that the button is disabled when it should not be?

Comment: Perhaps it's due to the syntax error.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals the save button is to be disabled until a change has been made and then the button is enabled and then once it is clicked it will disable again. but the data isn't actually being saved.

Comment: Maybe it is related to syntax error - missing `}` for Views.Accounts object

Comment: @Derek - no i just copied it wrong in here. is there supposed to be a disabled true or false?

Comment: Would you edit the post and copy the code correctly, so that we would identify the root cause of your case?

Comment: What's `$.views`? Is it another copy+paste typo, a jQuery plugin you haven't mentioned or a misspelling for `Views`? Don't you really see anything in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @AlvaroG.Vicario i am inserting this into a bundle and called from a view page to be applied to the buttons but i am thinking about disabling process of the button that doesn't allow the information to be saved but just sits there on the page until it refreshes and displays the data before the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem after doing some research - i actually had to pass in the button and its type:

```
(function ($) {

Views.Accounts = {
    AddSaveBtnEvents: function () {
        $('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $('#Username,#ProfileName').keyup(function(event) {
            $(event.target).siblings('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

        $('button[type=submit').click(function () {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    } 
};

$.views.Accounts.AddSaveBtnEvents();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So your save button does *not* have `savebtn` class?

Comment: it does which is the weird part but now it is working after that change.

Comment: You should use `.prop('disabled',true);` not attr methinks http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop- and of course `.removeProp()`  http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/